# Subform prevent Table Funktion

Tags: java, html, jsf-1.2, myfaces

I have following issue and I stuck to it. For a better understanding i made a little sketch. [image]

**Background:**
I have a regular form (black), this form is bound to some abstract validation, which is triggered by pressing a button (blue), so I can not change the behaviour for this special case. Now there is a new button (green), which is responsible to evaluate the subformarea (red), using the same abstract validation but only for the subformarea (red).

**Problem:**
The green Button is doing a good job, for the subform. The bad subform encapsulate the parent form (black). For this reason the blue buttons validation is not more working for the subformarea (red). If I use another component than a subform, the validation of the green button is not more working but the blue buttons ones is.

**How it should be:**
The blue botton should validate the black and the red form, but the green button is only responsible for the red form.

**How I tried to solve the problem:**
I tried different kinds of forms, a4j and jsf components to avoid the myfaces behaviour. Also I searched a possibility, to tell the forms (black and red), that the black form is a  parent form, for the red one. That the red one inherit his parents behaviour but not otherwise. Until now I couldn't find a solution.

I would be thankful for any kind of ideas how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code would be useful

Comment: It's not my code I can't post it.

Comment: Then how can we help?

Comment: But, [we want the funk](http://youtu.be/NDaLjuMKzYA)(tion).

Comment: Any kind of ideas, how to solve this problem, could be helpful.